# Android listview adapter creating rows based on parent and children

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

```
"parent": [
       {        
           "type": "Category",
           "label": "Transition",    
           "isButtonGroup": false,
           "children": [
                  {
                       "label": "Date Of case (Est.)",
                       "questionType": "DateTime",
                  },
                  {
                       "label": "Benchmark",
                       "questionType": "Float",
                  },

@Override
    public Children getItem(int position) {
          .....
        return Children ;
    }
```

case1: i want to display one children one row.

case2: i want to display all children in one row.

because my getView() method is getting called for each children, its displaying only first case.

I am not able to get case2, Any help or hint will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What't the content of your Children class? Do you save each child String in an Array, ArrayList, ...?

Comment: i have two models , one for Parent and one for child. In adapter class m getting                                                          ArrayList<Pair<ArrayList<Parent>, ArrayList<Children>>> data;.                         but my getItem works based on Children

Comment: I am not sure that I understand this. What's Pair?

Comment: my listview is having sections , all Parent labels are sections and Arraylist of childrens are rows.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the getView() method of your custom adapter, if you want to have one row for all the children then add this foreach loop:

**Assumptions**:
- allTheChildren is the ArrayList that contains all the Children of the parent that called the custom adapter.
- the getValue() method is the one that returns the content of the child.
- rowView = the layout that represents each line in your ListView.
- textView = the textView where you set the Children (this is part of the rowView layout).

```
String theFinalStrng = "";     
for (Child c : allTheChildren) {
    theFinalString = theFinalString + c.getValue() + " ";
}
textView.setText(theFinalString);
return rowView;
```

This way, if you have more than one children, you iterate through them and append them in a string that at the end you add to the textview, so in the same row.

I am missing valuable information here so I can't suggest exactly the code you need to write. Replace with appropriate variables and types that you have.

Comment: I am able to do the same, but the problem is my getView() method is getting called = "childs count" for that parent. for eg. if parent is having 5 children, getView() is getting called five times for the same parent. but i want getView() should get call once only for that parent.

Comment: I only make assumptions as I don't have your code. Where you call your custom adapter you most probably call it by iterating through the children ArrayList. Create (if you don't have one) a method to get all the Parents and iterate through that ArrayList that is returned by the new method. I can't give a better solution if I don't have the code.

Comment: I got a solution, i need to change my getView() method. i have to return different object based on the boolean.                                                             @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
          .....
        return Object ;
    }                                                                                                                 now i have to cast the object in parent or children. based on condition.